# jQuery Create a ui list from a string with classes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, list, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a variable called allVals which contains my list of items then its gets set to toString() and the list is the put in a div.

This list i want to be a list item, which would look like: -

```
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Sat Nav</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Alloy Wheels</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">etc etc</li>
</ul>
```

Here is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/uJcB7/171/

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

```
var target = $('.target');
var ul = $('<ul />');

target.append(ul);

$.each(allVals, function(_, item){
   ul.append('<li>' + item + '</li>');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mrobin/pnjma/)**

Comment: Yes, that should work. I have kept it as readable as possible. You should simply your fiddle too and keep only the parts relevant to your question.

Comment: I have simplified the fiddle, I am new to jQuery! http://jsfiddle.net/uJcB7/172/ cant get the items in the div when checked as a list. The ul and li's need classes and not sure how to get it all working.